# How do I list category name?

Tags: templating, categories

Forgive the simplicity of this question but I am in the early stages of my first Craft implementation.

My simple question is: how do I display a category name in a template. This is the code I am using:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.find({section: 'blog', limit: '3'}) %}
    <div class="article">
        <p class="category">{{ entry.blogCategory }}</p>
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="headline">{{ entry.title }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The error I am getting says "Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string"

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) is "used to fetch elements with a given set of parameters." `{{ entry.blogCategory }}` hasn't yet fetched your category element.

You need:

```
<p class="category">{{ entry.blogCategory.first }}</p>
```

if you are positive there is exactly one of them, or more generally:

```
{% for c in entry.blogCategory %}
  <p class="category">{{ c }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways. Categories in Craft are [elements](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements). Most things are. I wrote [an answer about relating elements here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/630/how-do-i-pull-related-entries-and-assets/640#640). For you, if you know there's just one you can:

```
<p class="category">{{ entry.blogCategory.first() }}</p>
```

If there's many you can loop over them:

```
{% for category in entry.blogCategory %}
    <p class="category">{{ category }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

If you just want a comma separated list:

```
<p class="category">{{ entry.blogCategory.find()|join(", ") }}</p>
```

I haven't tried the last one, but it should theoretically work.